# Optimizing IIS7 for .NET development and debugging

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis, iis-7

It seems like I spend nearly half of the time in .NET twiddling my thumbs waiting for IIS to spin up instead of actually developing.

It's pretty simple: Whenever I make a chance to a code-behind file, and refresh, it takes anywhere from 15 seconds to over a minute for IIS to recycle.

Is there any way to improve this? It's maddening.

I'm working in web site projects (not web application projects), running Windows 7 and working in the .NET 4 framework. My machine is just a few months old, with an SSD, so I don't think hardware should be the bottleneck.

Also, I'm not even actually debugging the application most of the time, though that runs even slower.

Comment: That's normal, avoid to test a page after each single change in your C# files.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

No matter what type of IIS you use, one of the best ways to speed things up is to create a RAM drive and point your TEMP and *especially* `ASP.NET Temporary Files` folders to it. ASP.NET Temporary Files contains the compiled binaries for your pages. ASP.NET checks this folder when it starts and only recompiles pages that have changes. Putting this folder on a RAM Drive will increase startup time by orders of magnitude. The technique is described in multiple articles, eg. in "[Slash your ASP.NET compile/load time without any hard work](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx)"

As an added bonus, you'll also reduce the wear and tear on your SSD .

**Original**

***For Web Applications***

It sounds like you have set your project to use Visual Studio Development Server or IIS Express instead of the IIS service local to your machine. When this happens, there is a significant delay as Dev Server starts from zero.

This is the default setting for new web projects. The Development Server is useful because it starts your project as the root virtual directory on a random available port. The disadvantage is that it takes an annoyingly long time to start.

You can speed things up significantly by changing your project to use your local IIS and start under a specific virtual directory. In this case the server is already running and the only thing needed is for the application pool to recycle. App pool recycling is actually very fast and you probably won't notice any delay unless you have a *lot* of code embedded in aspx pages, that requires recompilation on each recycle.

To change the type of server used for debugging, go to your web application's *Properties > Web* and in the `Servers` section, change the selection from Development Server to Local IIS. You will have to create a virtual directory for your application, but this can be done easily by typing the required URL in the `Project Url` textbox and pressing the "Create Virtual Directory" button.

***For Web Site Projects***

The impact of IIS Express/Visual Studio Dev Server vs a local IIS instance holds for Web Site projects as well. File-based web sites use the dev server by default. The process of changing to the local IIS service is different. Thankfully, it is described in detail at [How to: Specify the Web Server for Web Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I doubt he would explicitly specify IIS7 if he meant IIS Express.  Also, given that he's using a Web Site project, yes, it does compile everything every time the page is accessed.  Also, IIS Express does not shutdown and "start from 0" every time you rebuild.  IIS Express is the same code as IIS, except it runs in user mode (not as a service).  The big advantage is that it doesn't require running Visual Studio as an administrator to debug it.

Comment: File-based web sites use IIS Express. 15 secs is a huge delay for IIS-hosted projects

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am already using IIS7 and not IIS express. I'm familiar with the latter and the extra delay that causes as I've used it for debugging before. Thank you though for the information about creating a RAM drive, I hadn't heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how Web Site projects work.  Each file is compiled after every change, behind the scenes, into its own DLL.  There is no way to change this.

Now, how long it takes depends on your code.  There are things you can do to improve speed.  You can clean out your ASP.NET temporary files folder in \Windows\Microsoft.NET and you can strip out any references you are not using or any using statements you are not using.  This will reduce the compilation time.

Web site projects are really not well supported anyways, and have many disadvantages.  The only real advantage is compile on the fly, which as you are finding out is not that great of a benefit anyways.

You might want to read this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

> For new development, we recommend that you choose web application projects. This topic explains that web site projects have some advantages, but many developers who choose web site projects eventually find that the disadvantages outweigh any perceived advantages. In addition, as new ASP.NET features are developed, they won’t always be made available for web site projects. For example, the next Visual Studio release after Visual Studio 2012 will have new tooling for creating web projects, and this new tooling will work only with web application projects.

Comment: The ASP.Net Temporary files folder keeps the precompiled files. Cleaning it will increase the delay by forcing recompilations even for files that hadn't changed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I don't mean cleaning it every time.  When this folder gets lots of junk in it, it takes longer to scan for assemblies, so IIS doesn't know if it has to recompile or not.